# iOS - UITableView height autoresize not working when using insertSubview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, iphone-5, autoresizingmask

I'm working on an iPhone app with iOS 5.1 using Storyboards.  I have a UIViewController with a UITabBar component at the bottom.  I'm using the UITabBar delegate event `didSelectItem` to load in different view controllers to use for each tab page using `insertSubview` for example :

```
[[self view] insertSubview:[salesQuotesVC view] belowSubview:mainTabBar];
```

The view controller I'm inserting into the host view contains a UITableView control with all autosizing anchors/constraints enabled so it should stretch to the available space.  It also has simulated metrics Top Bar=Navigation Bar and Bottom Bar=Tab Bar.  Everything works fine except for the resizing of the UITableView when switching between 3.5" and 4" (iPhone 5) screens.  If I set Interface Builder to 3.5" form factor then it runs fine on a 3.5" device, but the table is too short on a 4" device.  Likewise if I set the IB form factor to 4" it runs fine on a 4" device but the table is too long and runs underneath the tab bar on a 3.5" device.

I've never had problems with autoresizing between 3.5"/4" devices before, but so far I've only ever used UITabViewControllers for tab pages.  This is the first time I've coded the tab switching myself using a UITabBar and UIViewController (I'm doing it for reusability purposes).  I'm guessing the resize issues are to do with the `insertSubview` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't had problems before because the view controller has done it for you. If you're adding the view as a subview then you need to do it yourself. Simply set the frame of the table view before you add it as a subview and then your autoresizing rules will take care of any subsequent changes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  So I need to check the size of the screen in use and then set the frame of the table view accordingly?

Comment: Set the table view frame in relation to the view you are going to add it to. So the view width and height minus the tab bar (which I guess is also a sub view) height.

Comment: That's brilliant, just had to take off an extra 44 for the navigation bar too.  Many thanks.